# Trouble with Backbone.Collection.extend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a backbone collection using the extend method. I get the following responses in my JS console:

```
$ var collection1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
$ var collection2 = new Backbone.Collection();
$ collection1
>> function()
$ collection2
>> Object { length=0, models=[0], _byId={...}, more...}
```

Why doesn't collection1 return the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is:

```
var Collection1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  foo: function (bar) {...}

});
var aCollection = new Collection1();
```

Now, Collection1 is a constructor of Collection1 instances, whereas aCollection is an object of type Collection1.

Answer (score 1):

Collection1 is a new "Class" (I come from c# so I see it that way).  So when you view it, you're actually seeing the constructor for that class

Collection2 is an instance (b/c of the `new` keyword) so you're seeing an actual instance of a collection.